# Creating multivariate distribution using marginal: can I use a copula?

Tags: joint-distribution, copula, marginal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I am modeling a multivariate distribution, where I already have the distributions of the marginals. Let's call the marginals, $f_{i}(x)$ for every $i$ marginal distribution, where $i=1,2,3$. We already know that $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are Gaussian $N(0,
\sigma_{i})$, while $f_{3}(x)$ is unknown, however, for $f_{3}(x)$ we have already modeled the univariate distribution (non-parametrically) and we have it's histogram. Let's not get into the details of $f_{3}(x)$ since that is out of scope for the discussion, and take it as given.

I am trying to combine these distributions. One way that I thought of is to use a copula. However, as far as I know, to combine the data into a copula I need the data to be $U[0,1]$. For $f_{3}(x)$ I can do this by taking the probability integral transform using the empirical CDF. However, for the Gaussians, I am not sure how to proceed. Should I simulate from the distributions and then use $F_{i}^{-1}$ to get to the uniforms? This doesn't sound right to me.

The problem is that I don't have the actually data. Essentially the problem is the following: consider $x_{1,t}$ being 1-day log-return, i.e., $x_{1,t} = log(\frac{P_{1,t}}{P_{1,t-1}})$. Now, the problem is, we have the distribution of $x_{1,t}$, say, $N(0,\sigma_{1,t,1D})$, but we don't know the distribution of the 1-year returns. We can use the 'square root of time' rule, to scale the daily standard deviation to an annual standard deviation, and we now have the annual Gaussian $N(0,\sigma_{1,t,1Y})$ (let's not go into the assumptions that have to hold here and take them as given).

Comment: If you do not have the data, then I do not think you can estimate the joint distribution. Either you have the full distribution and then can simulate data from it, or you have the data and then can estimate the joint distribution. But if you have neither, I do not think you can recover either.

Comment: As @Richard points out, it does no good just to make stuff up out of nothing.

Comment: I agree, any other suggestions?

Comment: Obtain relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in obtaining a multivariate distribution, you cannot simulate from the marginals as you do not yet know how they are related. You can use the actual data, however, and apply probability integral transform (based on the assumption of $N(0,\sigma_i)$) on them. Thus you obtain your $U[0,1]$ variates that can be used for fitting a copula.

Comment: I modified my answer to explain why I cannot do that.

Comment: Just transfer all the variables (if you have your data) into copula data using the `pobs` function in the R package `vineCopula.` Then, you can use the vine copula model.